# Trigger a Release (CD) pipeline from Build (CI) pipeline YAML file in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, devops, continuous-deployment

I am trying to figure out, How to trigger **Release (CD) pipeline** from a **Build (CI) pipelines YAML file** in **Azure DevOps CICD**. So is there a possibility to trigger like that is my first question.

My second question is: If we can trigger a Release pipelines from Build pipelines YAML file then how to write a stage for that. For Eg. Once we trigger from build pipeline, it should be like **trigger and forget**, means the CI pipeline should not wait for the CD pipeline should get complete, it should trigger it and complete its process. The CD pipeline should gets trigger once the CI pipeline sends a trigger to it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to trigger your release pipeline you should navigate on the Release pipelines and edit the continuous deployment trigger.

[image]

There you should select enable and whenever a build runs it can also trigger your release.

[image]

The way the procedure works is that when a build is completed then the release pipeline will be triggered. In order to trigger a release pipeline regardless of the build pipeline execution you should use the Azure devops rest API

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I have few things to ask, added a screenshot to get it clarified from the Continuous deployment trigger which one needs to be enabled and tried with one of the option by enabling it as you suggested, but it triggers the **Release** along with the **Build** pipeline. Could you please help here

Comment: The continuous deployment trigger will create a release after your build is completed. The pull request trigger explains that it will create a release every time a selected artifact is available as part of a pull request workflow. The selection depends on your strategy